# Rails 4 + Capistrano 3: deploy:check not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano

I can SSH successfully to my server. However, when I do `deploy:check`, it gives me this:

```
Nets-Mac-Pro:mysite emai$ be cap staging deploy:check
INFO[e67f845c] Running /usr/bin/env mkdir -p /tmp/mysite-staging/ on mysite-staging.nettheory.com
DEBUG[e67f845c] Command: /usr/bin/env mkdir -p /tmp/mysite-staging/
Text will be echoed in the clear. Please install the HighLine or Termios libraries to suppress echoed text.
Enter passphrase for /Users/emai/.ssh/id_rsa: 
Enter passphrase for /Users/emai/.ssh/id_rsa:         
Enter passphrase for /Users/emai/.ssh/id_rsa:
SSHKit::Runner::ExecuteError: Exception while executing on host mysite-staging.nettheory.com: Could not parse PKey: no start line
/Users/emai/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@mysite/gems/net-ssh-2.9.1/lib/net/ssh/key_factory.rb:77:in `read'
/Users/emai/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@mysite/gems/net-ssh-2.9.1/lib/net/ssh/key_factory.rb:77:in `load_data_private_key'
/Users/emai/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@mysite/gems/net-ssh-2.9.1/lib/net/ssh/key_factory.rb:42:in `load_private_key'
/Users/emai/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@mysite/gems/net-ssh-2.9.1/lib/net/ssh/authentication/key_manager.rb:142:in `sign'
/Users/emai/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@mysite/gems/net-ssh-2.9.1/lib/net/ssh/authentication/methods/publickey.rb:62:in `authenticate_with'
/Users/emai/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@mysite/gems/net-ssh-2.9.1/lib/net/ssh/authentication/methods/publickey.rb:20:in `block in authenticate'
/Users/emai/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@mysite/gems/net-ssh-2.9.1/lib/net/ssh/authentication/key_manager.rb:122:in `block in each_identity'
/Users/emai/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@mysite/gems/net-ssh-2.9.1/lib/net/ssh/authentication/key_manager.rb:119:in `each'
/Users/emai/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@mysite/gems/net-ssh-2.9.1/lib/net/ssh/authentication/key_manager.rb:119:in `each_identity'
/Users/emai/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@mysite/gems/net-ssh-2.9.1/lib/net/ssh/authentication/methods/publickey.rb:19:in `authenticate'
/Users/emai/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@mysite/gems/net-ssh-2.9.1/lib/net/ssh/authentication/session.rb:79:in `block in authenticate'
/Users/emai/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@mysite/gems/net-ssh-2.9.1/lib/net/ssh/authentication/session.rb:66:in `each'
/Users/emai/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@mysite/gems/net-ssh-2.9.1/lib/net/ssh/authentication/session.rb:66:in `authenticate'
/Users/emai/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@mysite/gems/net-ssh-2.9.1/lib/net/ssh.rb:206:in `start'
/Users/emai/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@mysite/gems/sshkit-1.5.1/lib/sshkit/backends/connection_pool.rb:50:in `call'
/Users/emai/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@mysite/gems/sshkit-1.5.1/lib/sshkit/backends/connection_pool.rb:50:in `create_new_entry'
/Users/emai/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@mysite/gems/sshkit-1.5.1/lib/sshkit/backends/connection_pool.rb:22:in `checkout'
/Users/emai/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@mysite/gems/sshkit-1.5.1/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh.rb:179:in `with_ssh'
/Users/emai/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@mysite/gems/sshkit-1.5.1/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh.rb:131:in `block in _execute'
/Users/emai/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@mysite/gems/sshkit-1.5.1/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh.rb:128:in `tap'
/Users/emai/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@mysite/gems/sshkit-1.5.1/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh.rb:128:in `_execute'
/Users/emai/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@mysite/gems/sshkit-1.5.1/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh.rb:66:in `execute'
/Users/emai/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@mysite/gems/capistrano-3.2.1/lib/capistrano/tasks/git.rake:17:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
/Users/emai/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@mysite/gems/sshkit-1.5.1/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh.rb:54:in `instance_exec'
/Users/emai/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@mysite/gems/sshkit-1.5.1/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh.rb:54:in `run'
/Users/emai/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@mysite/gems/sshkit-1.5.1/lib/sshkit/runners/parallel.rb:13:in `block (2 levels) in execute'
ArgumentError: Could not parse PKey: no start line
/Users/emai/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@mysite/gems/net-ssh-2.9.1/lib/net/ssh/key_factory.rb:77:in `read'
/Users/emai/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@mysite/gems/net-ssh-2.9.1/lib/net/ssh/key_factory.rb:77:in `load_data_private_key'
/Users/emai/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@mysite/gems/net-ssh-2.9.1/lib/net/ssh/key_factory.rb:42:in `load_private_key'
/Users/emai/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@mysite/gems/net-ssh-2.9.1/lib/net/ssh/authentication/key_manager.rb:142:in `sign'
/Users/emai/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@mysite/gems/net-ssh-2.9.1/lib/net/ssh/authentication/methods/publickey.rb:62:in `authenticate_with'
/Users/emai/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@mysite/gems/net-ssh-2.9.1/lib/net/ssh/authentication/methods/publickey.rb:20:in `block in authenticate'
/Users/emai/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@mysite/gems/net-ssh-2.9.1/lib/net/ssh/authentication/key_manager.rb:122:in `block in each_identity'
/Users/emai/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@mysite/gems/net-ssh-2.9.1/lib/net/ssh/authentication/key_manager.rb:119:in `each'
/Users/emai/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@mysite/gems/net-ssh-2.9.1/lib/net/ssh/authentication/key_manager.rb:119:in `each_identity'
/Users/emai/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@mysite/gems/net-ssh-2.9.1/lib/net/ssh/authentication/methods/publickey.rb:19:in `authenticate'
/Users/emai/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@mysite/gems/net-ssh-2.9.1/lib/net/ssh/authentication/session.rb:79:in `block in authenticate'
/Users/emai/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@mysite/gems/net-ssh-2.9.1/lib/net/ssh/authentication/session.rb:66:in `each'
/Users/emai/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@mysite/gems/net-ssh-2.9.1/lib/net/ssh/authentication/session.rb:66:in `authenticate'
/Users/emai/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@mysite/gems/net-ssh-2.9.1/lib/net/ssh.rb:206:in `start'
/Users/emai/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@mysite/gems/sshkit-1.5.1/lib/sshkit/backends/connection_pool.rb:50:in `call'
/Users/emai/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@mysite/gems/sshkit-1.5.1/lib/sshkit/backends/connection_pool.rb:50:in `create_new_entry'
/Users/emai/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@mysite/gems/sshkit-1.5.1/lib/sshkit/backends/connection_pool.rb:22:in `checkout'
/Users/emai/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@mysite/gems/sshkit-1.5.1/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh.rb:179:in `with_ssh'
/Users/emai/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@mysite/gems/sshkit-1.5.1/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh.rb:131:in `block in _execute'
/Users/emai/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@mysite/gems/sshkit-1.5.1/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh.rb:128:in `tap'
/Users/emai/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@mysite/gems/sshkit-1.5.1/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh.rb:128:in `_execute'
/Users/emai/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@mysite/gems/sshkit-1.5.1/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh.rb:66:in `execute'
/Users/emai/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@mysite/gems/capistrano-3.2.1/lib/capistrano/tasks/git.rake:17:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
/Users/emai/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@mysite/gems/sshkit-1.5.1/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh.rb:54:in `instance_exec'
/Users/emai/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@mysite/gems/sshkit-1.5.1/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh.rb:54:in `run'
/Users/emai/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@mysite/gems/sshkit-1.5.1/lib/sshkit/runners/parallel.rb:13:in `block (2 levels) in execute'
Tasks: TOP => git:check => git:wrapper
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
The deploy has failed with an error: #<SSHKit::Runner::ExecuteError: Exception while executing on host mysite-staging.nettheory.com: Could not parse PKey: no start line>
Nets-Mac-Pro:mysite emai$
```

It doesn't work no matter what I type, Also everything is out in the open. How do I fix this?

This is my deploy/staging.rb:

```
set :rails_env, 'staging'   
set :stage, :staging


role :app, %w{mysite-staging.nettheory.com}
role :web, %w{mysite-staging.nettheory.com}
role :db,  %w{mysite-staging.nettheory.com}
server 'mysite-staging.nettheory.com', user: 'nt_deployer', roles: %w{web app db}, primary: true

set :use_sudo, false
set :deploy_via, :copy
```

The above happens when I don't set the ssh_options. This is what happens when I set it:

```
set :ssh_options, {
    user: 'nt_deployer', # overrides user setting above
    keys: %w('/Users/emai/Downloads/ilook_ec2_07182014.pem'),
    forward_agent: true,
    auth_methods: %w(publickey)
    # password: 'please use keys'
  }


Nets-Mac-Pro:mysite emai$ be cap staging deploy:check
INFO[de1d1563] Running /usr/bin/env mkdir -p /tmp/mysite-staging/ on mysite-staging.nettheory.com
DEBUG[de1d1563] Command: /usr/bin/env mkdir -p /tmp/mysite-staging/
cap aborted!
SSHKit::Runner::ExecuteError: Exception while executing on host mysite-staging.nettheory.com: Authentication failed for user nt_deployer@mysite-staging.nettheory.com
/Users/emai/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@mysite/gems/net-ssh-2.9.1/lib/net/ssh.rb:219:in `start'
/Users/emai/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@mysite/gems/sshkit-1.5.1/lib/sshkit/backends/connection_pool.rb:50:in `call'
/Users/emai/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@mysite/gems/sshkit-1.5.1/lib/sshkit/backends/connection_pool.rb:50:in `create_new_entry'
/Users/emai/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@mysite/gems/sshkit-1.5.1/lib/sshkit/backends/connection_pool.rb:22:in `checkout'
/Users/emai/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@mysite/gems/sshkit-1.5.1/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh.rb:179:in `with_ssh'
/Users/emai/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@mysite/gems/sshkit-1.5.1/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh.rb:131:in `block in _execute'
/Users/emai/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@mysite/gems/sshkit-1.5.1/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh.rb:128:in `tap'
/Users/emai/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@mysite/gems/sshkit-1.5.1/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh.rb:128:in `_execute'
/Users/emai/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@mysite/gems/sshkit-1.5.1/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh.rb:66:in `execute'
/Users/emai/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@mysite/gems/capistrano-3.2.1/lib/capistrano/tasks/git.rake:17:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
/Users/emai/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@mysite/gems/sshkit-1.5.1/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh.rb:54:in `instance_exec'
/Users/emai/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@mysite/gems/sshkit-1.5.1/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh.rb:54:in `run'
/Users/emai/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@mysite/gems/sshkit-1.5.1/lib/sshkit/runners/parallel.rb:13:in `block (2 levels) in execute'
Net::SSH::AuthenticationFailed: Authentication failed for user nt_deployer@mysite-staging.nettheory.com
/Users/emai/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@mysite/gems/net-ssh-2.9.1/lib/net/ssh.rb:219:in `start'
/Users/emai/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@mysite/gems/sshkit-1.5.1/lib/sshkit/backends/connection_pool.rb:50:in `call'
/Users/emai/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@mysite/gems/sshkit-1.5.1/lib/sshkit/backends/connection_pool.rb:50:in `create_new_entry'
/Users/emai/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@mysite/gems/sshkit-1.5.1/lib/sshkit/backends/connection_pool.rb:22:in `checkout'
/Users/emai/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@mysite/gems/sshkit-1.5.1/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh.rb:179:in `with_ssh'
/Users/emai/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@mysite/gems/sshkit-1.5.1/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh.rb:131:in `block in _execute'
/Users/emai/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@mysite/gems/sshkit-1.5.1/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh.rb:128:in `tap'
/Users/emai/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@mysite/gems/sshkit-1.5.1/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh.rb:128:in `_execute'
/Users/emai/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@mysite/gems/sshkit-1.5.1/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh.rb:66:in `execute'
/Users/emai/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@mysite/gems/capistrano-3.2.1/lib/capistrano/tasks/git.rake:17:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
/Users/emai/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@mysite/gems/sshkit-1.5.1/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh.rb:54:in `instance_exec'
/Users/emai/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@mysite/gems/sshkit-1.5.1/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh.rb:54:in `run'
/Users/emai/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@mysite/gems/sshkit-1.5.1/lib/sshkit/runners/parallel.rb:13:in `block (2 levels) in execute'
```

Comment: check directory permission for `/home/nt_deployer/.ssh` for user `nt_deployer` for reading on the server

Comment: `drwx------ 2 nt_deployer nt_deployer 4096 Jul 18 19:30 .ssh`

Comment: `bundle update capistrano` or `bundle update net-ssh` solution from here http://coding-journal.com/argumenterror-could-not-parse-pkey-no-start-line/

Comment: Did both... nothing worked

Comment: could you try the solution https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano/issues/286

Comment: Well this is happening without specifying `set :ssh_options, {..}`. I updated the question with the results

Comment: @itsnikolay I think i managed to fix it by regenerating my ssh-key with `ssh-keygen`

Comment: can you explain why your key is located in '/Users/emai/Downloads/ilook_ec2_07182014.pem' ? not in `/Users/emai/.ssh/id_rsa` and `/Users/emai/.ssh/id_rsa.pub` ?

Comment: i think my last comment is why the issue happen.

Comment: I'm not sure what key I'm supposed to pointing at. Is it supposed to be my id_rsa.pub? or the mypew.pem file that amazon provided when I created the server