# Authentication failure with Capistrano version 3: Authentication failed for user@xxxxxxxxx

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano

I'm trying to deploy my application for the first time and everything seems to go fine up until Capistrano reaches my :db variable and that breaks because the authentication fails for a user named deployer. Deployer is shared by myself and my team members.

I've painstakingly read wikis and the followed the documentation on Capistrano regarding Preparing my application and Authentication/Authorization but something is still failing at the Authentication level at the git wrapper. Here is my error that I am receiving:

```
   INFO[0d3fe580] Running /usr/bin/env mkdir -p /tmp/openhub/ on deployer
DEBUG[0d3fe580] Command: /usr/bin/env mkdir -p /tmp/openhub/
INFO[610db5a4] Running /usr/bin/env mkdir -p /tmp/openhub/ on testing-crawl-1
DEBUG[610db5a4] Command: /usr/bin/env mkdir -p /tmp/openhub/
cap aborted!
Exception while executing on host testing-crawl-1: Authentication failed for user @testing-crawl-1
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/net-ssh-2.9.1/lib/net/ssh.rb:219:in `start'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/sshkit-1.5.1/lib/sshkit/backends/connection_pool.rb:50:in `call'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/sshkit-1.5.1/lib/sshkit/backends/connection_pool.rb:50:in `create_new_entry'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/sshkit-1.5.1/lib/sshkit/backends/connection_pool.rb:22:in `checkout'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/sshkit-1.5.1/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh.rb:179:in `with_ssh'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/sshkit-1.5.1/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh.rb:131:in `block in _execute'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/sshkit-1.5.1/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh.rb:128:in `tap'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/sshkit-1.5.1/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh.rb:128:in `_execute'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/sshkit-1.5.1/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh.rb:66:in `execute'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/capistrano-3.2.1/lib/capistrano/tasks/git.rake:17:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/sshkit-1.5.1/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh.rb:54:in `instance_exec'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/sshkit-1.5.1/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh.rb:54:in `run'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/sshkit-1.5.1/lib/sshkit/runners/parallel.rb:13:in `block (2 levels) in execute'
Tasks: TOP => git:check => git:wrapper
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Here is what I have deduced. The authentication seems to be failing for github determined by this line right here:

```
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/capistrano-3.2.1/lib/capistrano/tasks/git.rake:17:
```

Here is what I've tried.

- I have tried the [Cap Authentication/Authorization tutorial](http://capistranorb.com/documentation/getting-started/authentication-and-authorisation/)
- I have confirmed that my machine that I am deploying from (testing-utility-1) has the same 
  ssh key pairing as test-crawling-1 and testing-web-1(The server that I'm ultimately deploying too)
- I've read a lot of wikis regarding the failure including this stackoverflow answer [git.rake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24832625/rails-4-capistrano-3-deploycheck-not-working)
- I have tried a few configuration options in my deploy.rb and testing.rb which I will show below

Deploy.rb:

```
role :app, %w{testing-web-1}
role :web, %w{testing-web-1}
role :db, %w{testing-crawl-1}, primary: true}
role :user, 'deployer'
role :slave, "testing-crawl-1"
role :memcache, 'testing-web-1', no_release: true
set :stage, :testing
set :rails_env, :testing

server 'testing-web-1', user: 'deployer', roles: %w{web app}, primary: true

set :ssh_options, {
#    keys: %w(/home/rlisowski/.ssh/id_rsa),
forward_agent: true
#auth_methods: %w(password)
}
```

I've tried to change the keys parameter to point to my /home/deployer/.ssh/id_rsa
I've tried to set auth_methods: to %w(public_key)

Finally, my config/testing.rb

```
lock '3.2.1'
set :application, 'openhub'
set :repo_url, 'git@github.com:blackducksw/ohloh.git'
set :default_stage, 'testing'
set :use_sudo, false

set :deploy_to, "/var/local/#{fetch(:application)}"
set :pty, true
set :linked_files, %w{config/database.yml}
set :deploy_via, :remote_cache
```

I'm at a loss. I'm not sure why the authentication keeps failing and I'm out of leads to act on. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In case you're still having issues you can try using [capistrano-ssh-doctor](https://github.com/bruno-/capistrano-ssh-doctor) gem. It's used to debug capistrano ssh connections and issues just like this one.